# Android volley last request post call on network drop?

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley works well when there is network but it goes weird when network drops.

When network is doping ie network strength is going down and i make a post request then nothing happens but once the network regain to full strength it makes the call to the previous post request not the new one?

when i clear the cache it works well...

how to solve this issue, why i am getting previous post response?

```
// Implements required listeners
public class VolleyServices<T> implements Response.Listener<T>, ErrorListener{

private int id; // request id
private RequestQueue request; // volley request queue
private VolleyResponce<T> listener; // callback listener
private Class<T> clazz;  // parsing class

public interface VolleyResponce<T> {
    public void OnSuccess(T response,int id);
    public void OnError(ServerError error,int id);
}

// Constructor
public VolleyServices(VolleyResponce<T> listener,Context context) {
    this.listener = listener;
    request = VolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
}

// call to post the request with parse class, post parameters in map and request id
public void post(String methodName, HashMap<String, String> map,Class<T> clazz,int id) {
    String url = baseUrl + methodName;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.id = id;
    GsonRequest<T> myReq = new GsonRequest<T>(Request.Method.POST,url,clazz,map,this,this);
    myReq.setTag(id);
    request.add(myReq);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(T response) {
    if(response != null && clazz == response.getClass()){               
        listener.OnSuccess(response,this.id);                               
    }       
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

    ServerError error = null;

    if(volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
        error = new ServerError("No internet Access, Check your internet connection.","400");
    }

    if(volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
        error = new ServerError("Authentication Failure","400");
    }

    if(volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
        error = new ServerError("Parsing error","400");
    }

    if(volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        error = new ServerError("No internet Access, Check your internet connection.","400");
    }

    if(volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
        error = new ServerError("Request timed out, Please try again later.","400");
    }

    if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
        error = new ServerError("Internal server error","400");
    }

    else {
        try {
            if(volleyError.networkResponse != null) {
                String responseBody = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8" );
                try{
                    Gson gson = new Gson();         
                    error = gson.fromJson(responseBody, ServerError.class);
                    if(error.status == null) {
                        error.status = "";
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                error = new ServerError("Unknown Error","400");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    listener.OnError(error,this.id);
}
```

---

Some log message i captured which explains everything in detail
[log link](http://pastebin.com/0shpUnZi)

Comment: Can you add your code? Maybe you forgot about ErrorListener for volley request?

Comment: no i have errorlisteners... ill past some code

Comment: I can imagine you post few requests while network is down and the next time when network is working well you get one of your previous response. Any way could you say how many requests with same url you post while network is down? And also I noticed your `if else` blocks. Are you really want to use `if () {} if () {} if () {} ...` insted of `if () {} else if () {} else if () {} ...`

Comment: yes i did bit massed up with 'if..if..if' i did it because my server gives me error message if i do 'if..else' then i cannot override the server error message. and i posted only one request with the same url, i lock the button until it success, bt it does not so i close the app and re-post it and it gave he the previous response

Comment: here is the log link which explains every thing http://pastebin.com/0shpUnZi

Comment: @VikasRathod any idea how to solve this?